# Some questions about a proof referring to hyperbolic group

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

[image]

I feel confused about:

1:It says that "otherwise H contains an infinite cyclic characteristic subgroup C," however, by definition, if H is elementary, we can only get that H contains an infinite cyclic subgroup with finite index, why does that it imply H has an infinite cyclic characteristic subgroup?

2: Why $C_G$(C) has finite index in G?

3 Why C has finite index in $C_G(C)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer your questions 1 and 2. For 1, suppose that $H$ contains the cyclic subgroup $D$ of finite index. By replacing $D$ by its core in $H$ (i.e. the intersection of its conjugates in $H$), we may assume that $D\unlhd H$. Let $|H:D|=n$. Then $h^n \in D$ for all $h \in H$, and the subgroup $C:= \langle h^n \mid h \in H \rangle$ is characteristic in $H$ and is contained in $D$ with index at most $n$, so it is infinite cyclic.

Question 2 follows from the fact that ${\rm Aut}(C)$ is finite - in fact it has order $2$ and $G/C_G(C)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(C)$, so $|G/C_G(C)| \le 2$.

I am not familiar with all of the terminology. What is a special element? What does $E_G(H)$ mean? What does loxodromic mean?

Comment: Thank you very much, I have changed the third question, do you have any idea?

Comment: There is a theorem that the centralizer of an element in a hyperbolic group is itself a hyperbolic group. So  $C_G(C)$ is hyperbolic. A hyperbolic group with an element of infinite order in its centre must be elementary, since otherwise it would contain a subgroup ${\mathbb Z}^2$, which is impossible. So $C_G(C)$ is elementary and hence so is $G$, since $|G:C_G(C)|$ is elementary.

Comment: sorry, but how does it relate to the third question?

Comment: $C_G(C)$ elementary implies $|C_G(C):C|$ is finite. (Sorry, at the end I mean $|G:C_G(C)|$ is finite, not elementary!)

Comment: Thank you，that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, C is infinite cyclic, but why does the infinite cyclic subgroup with finite index have to be C?

Comment: Because $C_G(C)$ is elementary.

Comment: sorry, I know $C_G(C)$ is elementary, but by definition, it only implies it has an infinite cyclic subgroup with finite index, where do you get this infinite cyclic subgroup has to be C?

Comment: Please stop asking so many questions and think about it!